# How do I write this matrix as a product of elementary row matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

\begin{pmatrix}3&-1&3\\ -2&3&2\\ 1&-3&1\end{pmatrix}

Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
I have done this before with other matrices, yet this one is bringing me trouble. I have spent too long on this as I believe it should be easy and yet my answers are always wrong. What Do you do after you get the identity matrix?

What I am doing:
So I first row reduce it to the identity matrix:

- I first switch $R_1$ and $R_3$
- Then $R_3-3R_1$
- then $R_2+2R_1$
- then $-1/3R_2$
- then $R_3-8R_2$
- then $R_2-2R_1$
- then $3/32R_3$
- then $R_1+3R_3$
- and finally $R_2+4/3R_3$

I know there is many possible ways to get this too the identity matrix but this worked for me.
I then apply all of the above steps to identity matrices and multiply them together to check my work but it never works out to be the original matrix so I am forced to believe something is wrong.

Comment: "Some reason" is not helpful. What are you doing that's causing trouble?

Comment: Sorry, my apologies for being vague.  Basically when I row reduce it like normal I get that the solution set is inconsistent in the last row.

Comment: @GMuf Are you saying that this matrix is singular? Only non-singular matrices are products of elementary matrices.

Comment: Then it must be non singular as it does have an answer, I am just not doing it correctly.

Comment: If you have all of the operations that reduce $A$ to $I$  Then performing the reverse operation in reverse order, will give you the elementary operations to get from I back to $A.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not showing you matrices, I am guessing the most likely mistake is

$$R_2-2R_1$$

Should be

$$R_2\color{red}+2R_1$$

Edit:

Most likely another mistake is $R_3-8R_1$ should be $R_3-8R_\color{red}2$

Edit:

After you perform row operations:

$$E_k\ldots E_1 A = I$$

$$A =E_1^{-1} \ldots E_k^{-1} $$

Comment: Sorry typo! I did add it.

Comment: do you mind sharing the intermediate matrices.

Comment: Again, another typo. I know I did row reduce it correctly to the identity. I Just am not sure what to do from there.

Comment: did you solve for the matrix $A$ as described in my answer to  your duplicate post? what is the answer to that question?

Comment: I agree with Doug, but there could be a careless mistake lurking around in any of your steps... Including a careless mistake in multiplying matrices or  taking inverse. I don't think we have sufficient info to pinpoint the critical mistake yet. I am not sure if the mistake is of a careless nature of a conceptual error for now.

Comment: I think my question may be unclear... I am wondering what one does AFTER row reducing the matrix to the identity matrix.

Comment: From the row operations, we can construct the elementary matrices and take the inverse of those matrices. See my edit.